# How to Restore a prior item version as "current" in BIM360 via Autodesk-Data-Management-API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

In BIM360, how can I restore a file or plan (*item*) to a prior *version*. 
This is possible in the BIM360 UI, see attached Snip.

Interestingly in the BIM360 UI the restored versions show the old version number (in this example **V3**) are restored documents a *new item* or an *old one*??

[Snip from BIM360 "Restore"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYTde.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following endpoint to restore the file version to a previous one:

```
POST projects/:project_id/versions?copyFrom={version_urn}
{
    “jsonapi”: {
        “version”: “1.0”
    },
    “data”: {
        “type”: “versions”
    }
}
```

For details, please refer https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/delete-and-restore-file/ and https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-versions-POST/